# IP Address RegExp Simplification

Tags: javascript, regex, ip

My goal here is detecting rather or not a string is in an IP format (4 numbers separated by periods), the following statement works, but I feel like there must be a way to make shorter. If there is, please let me know. If not, that's fine too, I just want to know if there is.

```
/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/
```

Note that this is all in JavaScript.
Oh, and the only suggestion i'm looking for is shortening it. I don't need it any stricter than it is.

Comment: your statement does **NOT** work. take example `9898.2.2.34343434` or `555.555.555.555` are both ip addresses?

Comment: I do not need it to be strict. the only thing parsing through is legitimate ip addresses, i don't need to know if blank qualifies to be an ip, i need to know if it follows the num dot num dot num dot num structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about how long the number pattern is and just about the structure this should work and is more concise:

```
^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+
```

Comment: If shortness is the priority `[0-9]` would be better as `\d`. So `^(\d+\.){3}\d+$`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. 
Try with following Code

^([0-9]+.){3}[0-9]+

Answer (score 1):

Well if missing cases that Kent stated

> `9898.2.2.34343434` or `555.555.555.555`

is alright and your data is well behaved `^(\d+\.){3}\d+` would be a tiny bit shorter.
Trying to save bytes?

Comment: Yes, and i just have a problem with long code that does something that's hardly neccesary. What i'm doing is using it to toggle a "isIP" boolean for hosts that request my server.